# Storing a Value for use later without a Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a script which will run every 5 minutes, in order to check whether a certain number has increased:

```
   $oldmax = '1' //this is the number from the last result
   $newmax = '4' //this is the latest number
   If $newmax > $oldmax {runscript}
```

Since this is being run every 5 minutes, I need to query the $oldmax value, and then update it to the $newmax value if that max is greater than the old...

Currently I see the option to use MySQL to store the $oldmax value. However, since it's just one number being stored, I find it to be a bit of overkill to create a new table in MySQL, and then query that table for that one value which it stores. With PHP this adds a lot of extra code.

Is there another, more concise way to store the value of $oldmax, so that each time the cron runs, it can reference that value? Or do I need to use the database? If this were just a simple loop it would be easy, but my issue is the fact that the script runs every 5 minutes, so it has to keep starting from scratch.

Comment: can you clarify your answer please? I didn't understand "A file?..."

Comment: Write into a file. and read from the same file 5 min after :)

Comment: @Daniel C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file

Comment: You can also use the $_SESSION if session is enable (and the session timeout is greater than 5 min)

Comment: A tutorial on PHP file IO: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_files.htm

Comment: if you are not running the script with a browser-like, indeed, the session solution will not be available (as you have to send the session id at each run of your script). So, you can store into a file, its the simplest way.

Comment: @zerkms The file solution is the best. sorry for session, did not see it's run by cron.

Comment: @zerkms your answer worked. I have it now working using a simple file. Thanks!

Comment: @zerkms Your comments and manual links regarding `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents` are no longer here.  If you answer the question with this I'd vote and presumably you'd also get the accept from the OP?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to persist data in your case is to use filesystem.

There are handy [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents) functions to read and write data correspondingly.

Comment: +1. @DanielC the comment you used to solve your problem has now been posted as an answer by the person who originally suggested it.  If you have a moment, perhaps you could accept the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Write the value to a file like this. (suppose you use linux, if not let me know)

```
<?php 
exec('echo "VALUE" > file.txt');  //Linux Version
?>
```

To get the value from php, just do this..

```
<? $echo exec('cat file.txt'); //Linux Version ?>
```

You can also get the value directly from bash.

```
 cat /path-to-the-file/file.txt
```

Also remember to give php permissions to write on the directory. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php%5D) is the manual of the exec function.

Thanks!

@leo.

Comment: Your comment is not constructive at all. Fortunately there are several ways to do things like writing a file, or not?

Comment: +1 I agree with @zerkms that this is not _the best_ way to do this... possibly not even _a good_ way to do it when other purpose-built options are available within PHP that are more robust etc.  But it is _a way_ to do it that might prove useful or shed some light for this (or another) purpose and therefore adds some value to the post IMHO.

Comment: @lemil77: sure, but any pratical reason to prefer slow solution that is: 1. hard to maintain 2. OS specific 3. php configuration specific 4. Not friendly to multi-line strings ? I will remove my downvote as soon as you provide any **technical** reason to prefer your solution over `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents`

Comment: @Sepster: the real story: newbie won't think of how bad and stupid it is - he will just copy-paste and will use in production. So I don't see how this may be acceptable :-)

Comment: Yes, @zerkms, agree on those 4 points you mentioned. The other way is cleaner.

Comment: This is quite a strange occurance. A php script running on a cronjob not using a db calling shell functions.